# Django unable to load psycopg2 module. Python is also unable to load it, even though I see it when i run pip list

Tags: python, django, postgresql, macos

I cloned my personal project from my git repository onto my new laptop (mac, big sur, M1 chip) and I'm having some trouble with psycopg2.  I was able to get psycopg2 installed after a decent amount of headache.  All my dependencies should be installed.

Now, when I type python3 manage.py runserver I am greeted with the following error:

```html
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: /Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/users/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: /Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

It looks like django is having trouble loading psycopg2.  I base that on :

"raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)"

I know it is installed in my virtual environment, as I can see it when I run pip list.

When I run a python3 shell, and try to import psycopg2, I'm given the following error:

```html
Python 3.9.4 (v3.9.4:1f2e3088f3, Apr  4 2021, 12:32:44) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: /Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/jeff/Desktop/Project-BookBuddy/BookBuddy/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

I think the problem may have something to do with where python3 is looking for the psycopg2 module, but I'm pretty new to django (and brand new to macOS), so I'm not totally sure.  Do you think this is the case?  If so, how do I see where python is looking for the module, and how do I see where the module is actually located (should be in my virtual env I guess)?

Comment: try to install `psycopg2-binary` (already precompiled binaries etc) instead of `psycopg2` if that would help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have PostgreSQL installed in your machine, `pip install psycopg2-binary` would most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but in the documentation for psycopg2-binary, it does not recommend using it in production.  My database is already in production.

Comment: So your database is in production inside your new laptop? Okay...